# FirebaseCrash error with dump_syms when submitting to iOS App Store

Tags: ios, firebase, app-store-connect, firebase-crash-reporting

I've installed Firebase Crash into my app (without using CocoaPods) but, when I try to submit it to the iOS App Store, I get the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file
>   'xxxx.app/dump_syms' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain
>   standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable
>   of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at
>   https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on
>   the iOS app bundle structure."

Please note that, if I remove the dump_syms file from the bundle resources, the crash is correctly reported into Firebase but is not symbolized.

Someone suggested to read [Firebase issue #46](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/46) where they say that the warning problem during the build has been resolved, but it is not. I'm using the latest version of Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I asked to Firebase Support Team and they said that *dump_syms* should not be included in the bundle.

Probably the only way to have report properly symbolicated (if you use Apple's Bitcode) is to upload dSYMS files manually.

You can read more on [this issue I opened here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/255)